# MVVMLIGHT: MouseDoubleClick does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a listbox with EventTrigger MouseDoubleClick.

This **does not work**: EventName="MouseDoubleClick"

This **works**: EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp"

Here's the View

```
 <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" />
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding UserSelectionCommand}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding  SelectedItem, ElementName=MyListBox}"
                                                 />
         </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In ViewModel

```
public RelayCommand<string> UserSelectionCommand
{get; private set;}

UserSelectionCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ShowSelectedItem);

private void ShowSelectedItem(string selectedData)
{ .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing ListBox should be after the Interaction.Triggers, not before.

```
<ListBox> 
 <Interaction.Triggers>
 ..
<Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```